# Read Multiple raster with the same name contained in different folders

Tags: r, loops, directory, ascii, raster

I am a R beginner and I want to read multiple ASCII text files with the same name but located in different folders. I have a folder that contains other folders named after different species (e.g. `spp1`). Inside each species folder, different there are folders for different models (e.g. `model1`) and, inside *that* there are ASCII files with the same name (e.g. `var1.asc`).

Example listing:

```
$ find path -type f
path/spp1/model1/var1.asc
path/spp1/model2/var1.asc
path/spp2/model1/var1.asc
path/spp2/model2/var1.asc
```

For each species, I need to read the ASCII files of all models it has and calculate the median of the values between models.

I tried first to create the file path for the `spp1`, for example:

```
## Create a list file with the the species ##
setwd("mypath")
data <-list.files(pattern=".csv")
## Create the names of all the species by reading the files and deleting 4 characters (".csv") ##
for (i in 1:length(names)){
   names <- substr(data[i],1,nchar(data[i])-4)

## Then i tried to read in loop the ascii files only saves me the last ascii, not a list of all ##
## Once i have the names i create all the paths for the species ##
   path <- paste0("mypath", names)
## Then i create the subfolders for each model with and list that contains this names ##
   path_m <- paste0(path, Model[i])
   for (i in 1:length(names)){
      models <- list.files(path_m,
                     pattern = ".asc",
                     full.names = TRUE)
      stack <- raster::stack(models)}

## Calculate the median ##
   median(models)
   }
```

I would appreciate any help and thank you so much for your time.

---

### Edit

The name variable it is defined here as:

```
names <- substr(data[i],1,nchar(data[i])-4)
```

The original code is (formatted by editor):

```
library(raster)

## crear un listado de los nombres de mis especies ##
BASEDIR <- "D:/7_Doctorado/Sceloporus/3_Models/kuenm"

data <- list.files(file.path(BASEDIR, "1_Joint"), pattern=".csv")

for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    names <- substr(data[1], start=1, stop=nchar(data[1]) - 4)

    path_cal <- file.path(BASEDIR, paste0("ResultCalibracion_", names))
    setwd(path_cal)
    cal_res <- read.csv("best_candidate_models_OR_AICc.csv")
    row_names <- cal_res[, 1]

    for (i in 1:length(row_names)) {
        path <- file.path(BASEDIR,
                          paste0("Final_Models_", names),
                          paste0(row_names[i],"_NE"))
        models <- list.files(path,
                             pattern = "M_median.asc",
                             full.names = TRUE)
        stack <- raster::stack(models)
    }
    median_sp <- median(models)
    sd_sp <- sd(models)
    setwd(file.path(BASEDIR, "2_Models"))
    writeRaster(median_sp, filename=paste0(names, "_median"), format="ascii")
    writeRaster(sd_sp, filename=paste0(names, "_sd"), format="ascii")
}
```

It is hard to understand if you don't have the full context, that is why I prefer to explain the logic behind my question. The code above generates no errors, but the loop only reads the last ASCII file.

Comment: Please indent the code examples posted here following some code style guide. You have non-indented nested loops and it's hard to read. If you execute one or two iterations of the loops in your snippet step-by-step and inspect the variables values as they change you'll probably find the error (for example, it seems that you loop over the `names` variable, which is not defined here, then assign to it in the outer `for` loop, and then loop over it again in the inner `for` loop. This may not be doing what you expect.

Comment: I edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was editing your question (indenting and simplifying the code a bit to facilitate its reading) and maybe I found the error.

In the original code you added, the first statement of the outer loop reads:

```
names <- substr(data[1], start=1, stop=nchar(data[1]) - 4)
```

But it probably should use `data[i]` (with a lower case letter **i** instead of a digit **1**).

To avoid this kind of error, R allows iterating over vectors or lists directly, without the need of indexes. For example, the beginning of the loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    names <- substr(data[i], start=1, stop=nchar(data[i]) - 4)
```

Could be rewritten as:

```
for (filename in data) {
    names <- substr(filename, start=1, stop=nchar(filename) - 4)
```

Or even using a specialized function to remove the filename extension:

```
for (filename in data) {
    names <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename)
    # Or as you knew the extension ("$" marks end-of-string):
    names <- sub('\\.asc$', '', filename)
```

Using these kinds of dialects prevents that types of lookalike character typos and off-by-one bugs that are common when using bare indices.